# How to asynchronously read to std::string using Boost::asio?

Tags: string, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm learning Boost::asio and all that async stuff. How can I asynchronously read to variable `user_` of type std::string? `Boost::asio::buffer(user_)` works only with `async_write()`, but not with `async_read()`. It works with vector, so what is the reason for it not to work with string? Is there another way to do that besides declaring `char user_[max_len]` and using `Boost::asio::buffer(user_, max_len)`?

Also, what's the point of inheriting from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>` and  using `shared_from_this()` instead of `this` in `async_read()` and `async_write()`? I've seen that a lot in the examples.

Here is a part of my code:

```
class Connection
{
    public:

        Connection(tcp::acceptor &acceptor) :
            acceptor_(acceptor), 
            socket_(acceptor.get_io_service(), tcp::v4())
        { }

        void start()
        {
            acceptor_.get_io_service().post(
                boost::bind(&Connection::start_accept, this));
        }

    private:

        void start_accept()
        {
            acceptor_.async_accept(socket_, 
                boost::bind(&Connection::handle_accept, this, 
                placeholders::error));
        }

        void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& err)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(user_),
                    boost::bind(&Connection::handle_user_read, this,
                    placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred));
            }
        }

        void handle_user_read(const boost::system::error_code& err,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
        }

        ...

        void disconnect()
        {
            socket_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
            socket_.close();
            socket_.open(tcp::v4());
            start_accept();
        }

        tcp::acceptor &acceptor_;
        tcp::socket socket_;
        std::string user_;
        std::string pass_;
        ...
};
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Boost.Asio documentation states:

> A buffer object represents a contiguous region of memory as a 2-tuple consisting of a pointer and size in bytes. A tuple of the form {void*, size_t} specifies a mutable (modifiable) region of memory.

This means that in order for a call to `async_read` to write data to a buffer, it must be (in the underlying buffer object) a contiguous block of memory.  Additionally, the buffer object must be able to write to that block of memory.

`std::string` does not allow arbitrary writes into its buffer, so `async_read` cannot write chunks of memory into a string's buffer (note that `std::string` *does* give the caller read-only access to the underlying buffer via the `data()` method, which guarantees that the returned pointer will be valid until the next call to a non-const member function.  For this reason, Asio can easily create a `const_buffer` wrapping an `std::string`, and you can use it with `async_write`).

The Asio documentation has example code for a simple "chat" program (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.chat) that has a good method of overcoming this problem.  Basically, you need to have the sending TCP send along the size of a message first, in a "header" of sorts, and your read handler must interpret the header to allocate a buffer of a fixed size suitable for reading the actual data.

As far as the need for using `shared_from_this()` in `async_read` and `async_write`, the reason is that it guarantees that the method wrapped by `boost::bind` will always refer to a live object.  Consider the following situation:

1. Your `handle_accept` method calls `async_read` and sends a handler "into the reactor" - basically you've asked the `io_service` to invoke `Connection::handle_user_read` when it finishes reading data from the socket.  The `io_service` stores this functor and continues its loop, waiting for the asynchronous read operation to complete.
2. After your call to `async_read`, the `Connection` object is deallocated for some reason (program termination, an error condition, etc.)
3. Suppose the `io_service` now determines that the asynchronous read is complete, *after* the `Connection` object has been deallocated but *before* the `io_service` is destroyed (this can occur, for example, if `io_service::run` is running in a separate thread, as is typical).  Now, the `io_service` attempts to invoke the handler, and it has an invalid reference to a `Connection` object.

The solution is to allocate `Connection` via a `shared_ptr` and use `shared_from_this()` instead of `this` when sending a handler "into the reactor" - this allows `io_service` to store a shared reference to the object, and `shared_ptr` guarantees that it won't be deallocated until the last reference expires.

So, your code should probably look something like:

```
class Connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
public:

    Connection(tcp::acceptor &acceptor) :
        acceptor_(acceptor), 
        socket_(acceptor.get_io_service(), tcp::v4())
    { }

    void start()
    {
        acceptor_.get_io_service().post(
            boost::bind(&Connection::start_accept, shared_from_this()));
    }

private:

    void start_accept()
    {
        acceptor_.async_accept(socket_, 
            boost::bind(&Connection::handle_accept, shared_from_this(), 
            placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            disconnect();
        }
        else
        {
            async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(user_),
                boost::bind(&Connection::handle_user_read, shared_from_this(),
                placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
    }
    //...
};
```

Note that you now must make sure that each `Connection` object is allocated via a `shared_ptr`, e.g.:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Connection> new_conn(new Connection(...));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 12):

This isn't intended to be an answer per se, but just a lengthy comment: a very simple way to convert from an ASIO buffer to a string is to stream from it:

```
asio::streambuf buff;
asio::read_until(source, buff, '\r');  // for example

istream is(&buff);
is >> targetstring;
```

This is a data copy, of course, but that's what you need to do if you want it in a string.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Boost.Asio can read from many buffer types, and write to many fixed-size buffers, but `asio::streambuf` is the only variable-size buffer it will work with. As MikeC correctly notes, this is a data copy, but `std::string` has internal copies when it grows anyway. Note that the extraction method `operator>>` is the usual whitespace-parsing method.from iostream. You can also call `getline` on the `istream`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `std:string` with `async\_read()` like this:

```
async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(&user_[0], user_.size()),
           boost::bind(&Connection::handle_user_read, this,
           placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

However, you'd better make sure that the `std::string` is big enough to accept the packet that you're expecting and padded with zeros before calling `async\_read()`.

And as for why you should **NEVER** bind a member function callback to a `this` pointer if the object can be deleted, a more complete description and a more robust method can be found here: [Boost async_* functions and shared_ptr's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356742/boost-async-functions-and-shared-ptrs).

Answer (score 2):

Boost Asio has two styles of buffers. There's `boost::asio::buffer(your_data_structure)`, which **cannot** grow, and is therefore generally useless for unknown input, and there's `boost::asio::streambuf` which **can** grow.

Given a `boost::asio::streambuf buf`, you turn it into a string with `std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&buf), {});`.

This is not efficient as you end up copying data once more, but that would require making `boost::asio::buffer` aware of growable containers, i.e. containers that have a `.resize(N)` method. You can't make it efficient without touching Boost code.