# How to use std::string with asio::buffer()

Tags: boost, buffer, boost-asio

I get the following error message when I'm trying to use std::string with boost::asio::buffer:

```
boost/asio/detail/consuming_buffers.hpp:
In constructor
'boost::asio::detail::consuming_buffers<
        boost::asio::mutable_buffer, boost::asio::const_buffers_1
    >::consuming_buffers(const boost::asio::const_buffers_1 &)':
boost/asio/impl/read.hpp:140:25:  
instantiated from
'boost::asio::detail::read_op<
        boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>,
boost::asio::const_buffers_1
      , boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t
      , boost::_bi::bind_t<
            void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, read_op, const
boost::system::error_code &>
          , boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<read_op
*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> 
        > 
    >::read_op(
        boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>
&, const boost::asio::const_buffers_1
&
      , boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t
      , boost::_bi::bind_t<
            void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, read_op, const
boost::system::error_code &>
          , boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<read_op
*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()>
        >
    )'

[...]
```

Full source code: http://liveworkspace.org/code/eca749f6f2714b7c3c4df9f26a404d86

Comment: look at this if you after 2 years are still curious : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790383/how-to-asynchronously-read-to-stdstring-using-boostasio

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are passing a const buffer to `async_read` instead of a mutable buffer. In the block ending in line 50, `boost::asio::buffer(_header)` returns a const buffer. You should do something like `boost::asio::async_read(s, boost::asio::buffer(data, size), handler)`, because `boost::asio::buffer(data, size)` creates a mutable buffer.

Instead of using `std::string`s for _header and _data, you probably need to use arrays of char, such as:

```
char* _data;
boost::asio::buffer(_data, strlen(_data));
```

See reference documentations for `buffer` and `async_read`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure std::strings can be assigned to char* arrays, and one can export the char* array from the std::string with std::string.c_str()

Comment: `std::string::c_str()` returns `const char*` not `char*`. It can only be used with `const_buffer`.

Answer (score 7):

From the [`boost::asio::buffer` reference documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html):

It seems that `std::string` could only be passed into an `asio::buffer` as a const reference.

`std::vector<char>` should be a better alternative:

```
std::vector<char> d2(128);
bytes_transferred = sock.receive(boost::asio::buffer(d2));
```

Answer (score 7):

You must pass a pointer as the first parameter:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

std::string request, reply;
auto rsize = boost::asio::buffer(&reply[0], request.size());
```

Comment: As a note, until C++11, this is not necessarily correct.  Pre-C++11, the char array held by std::string was not guaranteed to be contiguous, which is required by boost::asio::buffer.  In practice, every compiler uses a contiguous block of memory, and so this became required behavior in C++11.