# alternatives to std::string to use with boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

`boost::asio`'s various `read` and `write` functions and methods accept `boost::asio::buffer`. According to [buffer's documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html), a mutable `std::string` cannot be wrapped in `boost::asio::buffer`, and thus cannot be used for asio's `read` functions. This is probably due to the fact that `std::string` does not allow mutable access to its internal buffer (this was discussed previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790383/how-to-asynchronously-read-to-stdstring-using-boostasio/2795371#2795371)).

This is a shame, because `std::string` is a convenient way to represent mutable buffers of data in C++. Without it, we're either left with POD arrays, `boost::array` and `std::vector<char>`. The first two are inconvenient with variable-length messages. `std::vector<char>` can work, but it's an unnatural way to carry buffers of data around (*)

Questions:

1. Are there other alternatives to `std::string` with `boost::asio` for reading buffers? Am I missing something here?
2. I wonder why `std::vector<char>` *is* supported in a mutable buffer. Is it because it guarantees its internal buffer is contiguous in memory and allows mutable access to it with `&vec[0]` ?

Thanks in advance

---

(*) IMHO. Look at `protobuf` serialization for instance - it offers serialization into `std::string` but not into `std::vector<char>`, at least not explicitly.

---

**EDIT:** I ended up using `vector<char>` after all. `protobuf` allows serialization into a `vector<char>` by means of the `SerializeToArray` call which takes a pointer (`&vec[0]` can be passed there).

Comment: I normally use `vector<char>` - because I've found this to be faster in all my cases for processing operations on received data. However I have seen uses of uses of `asio::streambuf` as well: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html.

Comment: @Nim: I considered `asio::streambuf` but it appears problematic with fixed-size reads, and more suitable for `read_until` like in HTTP. But I may be missing something ...

Comment: @Eli: I've always found `std::vector<unsigned char>` to be the natural way to express a buffer of bytes. The unknown signedness of `char` is annoying... And semantically a `string` does not really make sense. Don't forget that `protobuf` proposes to serialize to plain text, in which case a `string` does appear natural.

Comment: @Mattieu M.: I don't think `protobuf` proposes to serialize to plain text, its serialization output definitely looks like binary data (not ascii)

Comment: @Eli I'm not sure what you mean by `asio::streambuf` being problematic for fixed size reads. I've used it successfully in several projects, it integrates nicely with Boost.Serialization. Could you edit your question to clarify your concerns?

Comment: @Sam: I didn't mention `asio::streambuf` in my question originally, indeed because it wasn't 100% clear to me how to use it with fixed size reads and asio. Could you point to an example (or add one as an answer) of showing how to read fixed-length chunks into a `std::sstream`?

Comment: @Eli, the link in my original comment shows how to do a read using the `asio::streambuf`. The only *annoying* aspect of using this buffer is that you have `commit` the count of bytes read before reading from the buffer...

Comment: @Eli I've added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248291/alternatives-to-stdstring-to-use-with-boostasio/5276059#5276059).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to answer Eli's comment

> I didn't mention asio::streambuf in my
>   question originally, indeed because it
>   wasn't 100% clear to me how to use it
>   with fixed size reads and asio. Could
>   you point to an example (or add one as
>   an answer) of showing how to read
>   fixed-length chunks into a
>   `std::sstream`?

Here's [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599638/how-can-i-wrap-stdwstring-in-boostasiobuffer/3600460#3600460) about using `asio::streambuf` and `Boost.Serialization`. The asio [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html) also has an example of a synchronous read:

```
boost::asio::streambuf b;

// reserve 512 bytes in output sequence
boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type bufs = b.prepare(512);

size_t n = sock.receive(bufs);

// received data is "committed" from output sequence to input sequence
b.commit(n);

std::istream is(&b);
std::string s;
is >> s;
```

Answer (score 8):

Mutable access to a string buffer using `&str[0]` works fine on all known implementations, and the wording of the upcoming C++0x standardizes makes it officially allowed.

Still, I think you're insane to think that a `std::vector` is an unnatural representation for a variable-length buffer.

Comment: Ben, this sounds good, but `asio::buffer` has no constructor taking non-const `std::string`, so how do you pass it into `asio`? Could it be that `asio` doesn't want to currently rely on behavior which isn't strictly standard?

Comment: Conversion from `std::string` to `asio::buffer`: `asio::buffer(&str[0], str.size())`

Comment: I see, but this is not currently standard C++? It's supported by convention and is supposed to be part of C++0X?

Comment: It's currently implementation-dependent, whether the string data exists in a contiguous array.  Before adding it to the C++0x standard draft, the committee surveyed all library implementations they could find and not a single one did anything non-contiguous.

Comment: @Ben: Do you have a reference to this survey, I'd like to read more about it?

Comment: Wouldn't str.c_str() give you the standard-guaranteed contiguous buffer pointer?

Comment: @Alan: There's no guarantee that changes made to the `c_str()` buffer are incorporated into the string, or that the buffer is even writable in the first place.

Comment: @murrekatt: Read the comments here: http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/   Herb Sutter is one of C++ standard committee members and formerly was the committee chair.

Answer (score 2):

1) alternatives can be found by checking [`asio::buffer()`](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_3_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) function, overloads that return `mutable_buffers_1`. more flexible (but probably sub-optimal) option is `asio::streambuf`, useful for `(async_)read_until`.

if you have fixed-size fields protocol you can use array of `asio::mutable_buffer`. e.g.

```
using boost::asio;
int i;
short s;
char data[data_size]; // data_size is defined elsewhere
boost::array<asio::mutable_buffer, 3> bufs = {
    asio::buffer(&i, 4), 
    asio::buffer(&s, 2),
    asio::buffer(data, data_size)
};
asio::read(socket, buffer(bufs)); // socket defined elsewhere
```

2) you already referenced great answer to this question: ["How to asynchronously read to std::string using Boost::asio?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790383/how-to-asynchronously-read-to-stdstring-using-boostasio/2795371#2795371)

Comment: Yes, indeed everything you list here was already mentioned in my question (including the fixed-array approach). Thanks for the reassurance, anyway :-)