# Boost async_* functions and shared_ptr's

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I frequently see this pattern in code, binding `shared_from_this` as the first parameter to a member function and dispatching the result using an `async_*` function. Here's an example from another question:

```
void Connection::Receive()
{
     boost::asio::async_read(socket_,boost::asio::buffer(this->read_buffer_),
        boost::bind(&Connection::handle_Receive, 
           shared_from_this(),
           boost::asio::placeholders::error,
           boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
 }
```

The only reason to use `shared_from_this()` instead of `this` is to keep the object alive until the member function gets called. But unless there's some kind of boost magic somewhere, since the `this` pointer is of type `Connection*`, that's all `handle_Receive` can take, and the smart pointer returned should be converted to a regular pointer immediately. If that happens, there's nothing to keep the object alive. And, of course, there's no pointer in calling `shared_from_this`.

However, I've seen this pattern so often, I can't believe it's as completely broken as it seems to me. Is there some Boost magic that causes the shared_ptr to be converted to a regular pointer later, when the operation completes? If so, is this documented somewhere?

In particular, is it documented somewhere that the shared pointer will remain in existence until the operation completes? Calling `get_pointer` on the strong pointer and then calling the member function on the returned pointer is not sufficient unless the strong pointer isn't destroyed until the member function returns.

Comment: When we wrote network layer for our project we added external stuff to guarantee that handler hasn't destroyed when connection established.

Comment: @PSyton: I did the same thing, writing `static` helper functions that explicitly take a `shared_ptr` and call the member function. But I see so much code that does it this way, I can't believe it's all broken. Yet, I can't see where it's documented to work either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In short, `boost::bind` creates a copy of the `boost::shared_ptr<Connection>` that is returned from `shared_from_this()`, and `boost::asio` may create a copy of the handler.  The copy of the handler will remain alive until one of the following occurs:

- The handler has been called by a thread from which the service's `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` member function has been invoked.
- The `io_service` is destroyed.
- The `io_service::service` that owns the handler is shutdown via [`shutdown_service()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__service/shutdown_service.html).

Here are the relevant excerpts from the documentation:

- boost::bind [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions):

  > The arguments that `bind` takes are copied and held internally by the returned function object.
- boost::asio [`io_service::post`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html):

  > The `io_service` guarantees that the handler will only be called in a thread in which the `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` member functions is currently being invoked. [...]  The `io_service` will make a copy of the *handler* object as required.
- boost::asio [`io_service::~io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html):

  > Uninvoked handler objects that were scheduled for deferred invocation on the `io_service`, or any associated strand, are destroyed.
  >   
  >   Where an object's lifetime is tied to the lifetime of a connection (or some other sequence of asynchronous operations), a `shared_ptr` to the object would be bound into the handlers for all asynchronous operations associated with it. [...] When a single connection ends, all associated asynchronous operations complete. The corresponding handler objects are destroyed, and all `shared_ptr` references to the objects are destroyed.

---

While dated (2007), the [Networking Library Proposal for TR2 (Revision 1)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2175.pdf) was derived from Boost.Asio.  Section `5.3.2.7. Requirements on asynchronous operations` provides some details for the arguments to `async_` functions:

> In this clause, an asynchronous operation is initiated by a function that is named with the prefix `async_`. These functions shall be known as *initiating functions*. [...] The library implementation may make copies of the handler argument, and
>   the original handler argument and all copies are interchangeable.
>
> The lifetime of arguments to initiating functions shall be treated as follows:
>
> - If the parameter is declared as a const reference or by-value [...] the implementation may make copies of the argument, and all copies shall be destroyed no later than immediately after invocation of the handler.
>
> [...] Any calls made by the library implementation to functions associated with the initiating function's arguments will be performed such that calls occur in a sequence call<sub>*1*</sub> to call<sub>*n*</sub>, where for all *i*, 1 ≤ *i* < *n*, call<sub>*i*</sub> precedes call <sub>*i+1*</sub>.

Thus:

- The implementation may create a copy of the *handler*.  In the example, the copied *handler* will create a copy of the `shared_ptr<Connection>`, increasing the reference count of the `Connection` instance while the copies of *handler* remain alive.
- The implementation may destroy the *handler* prior to invoking *handler*.  This occurs if the async operation is outstanding when `io_serive::service` is shutdown or the `io_service` is destroyed.  In the example, the copies of handler will be destroyed, decreasing the reference count of `Connection`, and potentially causing the `Connection` instance to be destroyed.
- If *handler* is invoked, then all copies of handler will immediately be destroyed once execution returns from the handler.  Again, the copies of handler will be destroyed, decreasing the reference count of `Connection`, and potentially causing it to be destroyed.
- The functions associated with the `asnyc_`'s arguments, will be executed sequentially, and not concurrent.  This includes `io_handler_deallocate` and `io_handler_invoke`.  This guarantees that the *handler* will not be deallocated while the *handler* is being invoked.  In most areas of the `boost::asio` implementation, the *handler* is copied or moved to stack variables, allowing the destruction to occur once execution exits the block in which it was declared.  In the example, this ensures that the reference count for `Connection` will be at least one during the invocation of the *handler*.

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on this pattern w.r.t. performance?  On each write or read a new shared_ptr will have to be created which is dealing with atomics/mutex and could slow things down considerably. Anyone have any thoughts on how to keep passing the same shared_ptr around instead of making a new one each time?

Comment: @schuess You want to create a new `shared_ptr` each time because you want to keep the object alive and you want the removal of the last one to remove the object. On modern CPUs, the cost is negligible because there will be almost no contention because the operations are inherently fast and typically take place on a virtual strand. Such an "optimization" would almost always be misguided.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, is it possible to declare that shared object as member of the a connection class to avoid using `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @SAMPro That would make it more difficult to ensure the shared object had a long enough lifetime. But it can be done that way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055104) regarding this, would you mind taking a look at it?

Answer (score 5):

It goes like this:

1) Boost.Bind documentation [states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers):

> "[Note: mem_fn creates function objects that are able to accept a
>   pointer, a reference, or a smart pointer to an object as its first
>   argument; for additional information, see the mem_fn documentation.]"

2) mem_fn documentation [says](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/mem_fn.html#Purpose):

> When the function object ***is invoked*** with a first argument x that is
>   neither a pointer nor a reference to the appropriate class (X in the
>   example above), it uses get_pointer(x) to obtain a pointer from x.
>   Library authors can "register" their smart pointer classes by
>   supplying an appropriate get_pointer overload, allowing mem_fn to
>   recognize and support them.

So, pointer or smart-pointer is stored in the binder as-is, until its invocation.

Answer (score 4):

I also see this pattern used a lot and (thanks to @Tanner) I can see why it's used when the `io_service` is run in **multiple threads**. However, I think that there are still lifetime issues with it as it replaces a potential crash with a potential memory/resource leak...

Thanks to boost::bind, any callbacks that are bound to shared_ptrs become "users" of the object (increasing the objects use_count), so the object won't be deleted until all of the outstanding callbacks have been called.

The callbacks to the boost::asio::async* functions are called whenever, cancel or close
is called on the relevant timer or socket. Normally you would just make the appropriate cancel/close calls in the destructor using Stroustrup's beloved [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) pattern; job done.

However, the destructor won't be called when the owner deletes the object, because the callbacks still hold copies of the shared_ptrs and so their use_count will be greater than zero, resulting in a resource leak. The leak can be avoided by making the appropriate cancel/close calls prior to deleting the object. But it’s not as fool-proof as using RAII and making the cancel/close calls in the destructor. Ensuring that the resources are *always* freed, even in the presence of exceptions.

An RAII conforming pattern is to use static functions for callbacks and pass a weak_ptr to boost::bind when registering the callback function as in the example below:

```
class Connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
  boost::asio::strand  strand_;
  /// shared pointer to a buffer, so that the buffer may outlive the Connection 
  boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > read_buffer_;

  void read_handler(boost::system::error_code const& error,
                    size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    // process the read event as usual
  }

  /// Static callback function.
  /// It ensures that the object still exists and the event is valid
  /// before calling the read handler.
  static void read_callback(boost::weak_ptr<Connection> ptr,
                            boost::system::error_code const& error,
                            size_t bytes_transferred,
                            boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > /* read_buffer */)
  {
    boost::shared_ptr<Connection> pointer(ptr.lock());
    if (pointer && (boost::asio::error::operation_aborted != error))
      pointer->read_handler(error, bytes_transferred);
  }

  /// Private constructor to ensure the class is created as a shared_ptr.
  explicit Connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) :
    socket_(io_service),
    strand_(io_service),
    read_buffer_(new std::vector<char>())
  {}

public:

  /// Factory method to create an instance of this class.
  static boost::shared_ptr<Connection> create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
  { return boost::shared_ptr<Connection>(new Connection(io_service)); }

  /// Destructor, closes the socket to cancel the read callback (by
  /// calling it with error = boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) and
  /// free the weak_ptr held by the call to bind in the Receive function.
  ~Connection()
  { socket_.close(); }

  /// Convert the shared_ptr to a weak_ptr in the call to bind
  void Receive()
  {
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer_),
          strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&Connection::read_callback,
                       boost::weak_ptr<Connection>(shared_from_this()),
                       boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                       boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                       read_buffer_)));
  }
};
```

Note: the `read_buffer_` is stored as a `shared_ptr` in the Connection class and passed to the `read_callback` function as a `shared_ptr`.

This is to ensure that where multiple `io_services` are run in separate tasks, the `read_buffer_` is not deleted until *after* the other tasks have completed, i.e. when the `read_callback` function has been called.

Comment: When multiple threads run the `io_service`, undefined behavior can occur as the lifetime of the underlying buffer memory and socket are no longer guaranteed to be at least as long as the handler.  It may be worth considering using an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) to decouple the desired RAII semantics with the underlying lifespan of resources.  This would allow the socket to be closed when user code no longer has a handle to `Connection`, yet still allow for the necessary resources to remain valid for the duration of the asynchronous operations.

Comment: Thanks @Tanner, I hadn't considered the buffer lifetime in the multi-threaded case. I've amended my answer to make it clear that the weak_ptr pattern should only be used in a single threaded environment. I'm interested in your `opaque pointer` solution, do you have an example?

Comment: While not exactly an opaque pointer, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d510aefd42539b2c) is a quick example that provides RAII semantics to the user, while decoupling it from the object's lifetime.

Comment: Thank you @Tanner, the example was interesting. However, I felt that the simplest way to provide multi-threading support in my answer was simply to put the buffer in a `shared_ptr` and pass it in the `bind` to the callback so that it may outlive the Connection class.

Answer (score 2):

There is no conversion from `boost::shared_ptr<Connection>` (the return type of `shared_from_this`) to `Connection*` (the type of `this`), as it would be unsafe as you rightfully pointed out.

The magic is in Boost.Bind. To put it simply, in a call of the form `bind(f, a, b, c)` (no placeholder or nested bind expression involved for this example) where `f` is a pointer to member, then calling the result of the call will result in a call of the form `(a.*f)(b, c)` if `a` has a type derived from the class type of the pointer to member (or type `boost::reference_wrapper<U>`), or else it's of the form `((*a).*f)(b, c)`. This works with pointers and smart pointers alike. (I'm actually working from memory the rules for `std::bind`, Boost.Bind is not exactly identical but both are in the same spirit.)

Furthermore, the result of `shared_from_this()` is stored in the result of the call to `bind`, ensuring that there are no lifetime issues.

Comment: The issue is when `*f` is evaluated and what the lifetime of `*f` is. If those are guaranteed to be what is needed for this use, where is that documented?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Remember that there is a call wrapper (let's call it `w`), i.e. the result of the call to `bind`, that holds a copy of the smart pointer. When doing the equivalent of `w(x, y, z)` that copy is not going away -- `w` will stay alive until at least the end of the call.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but the shared_ptr returned by `shared_from_this()` is stored in the function object returned by `boost::bind`, which keeps it alive. It's only implicitly converted to `Connection*` at the time when the callback is launched when the async read finishes, and the object is kept alive for at least the duration of the call. If the `handle_Receive` doesn't create another shared_ptr from this, and the shared_ptr that was stored in the bind functor is the last shared_ptr alive, the object will be destroyed after the callback returns.

Comment: What ensures the object is kept alive for at least the duration of the call? Where is that documented?

Comment: Because you can't call the `operator()` of the bind functor, if the function object doesn't exist anymore. :P Only after the `operator()` of the bind functor returns, can the functor be destroyed logically.

Comment: I'm not comfortable relying on reasoning about the way a function must be implemented on the grounds that we can't think of any other way to do it. I'm really only comfortable relying on the guaranteed semantics of an operation.