# Detect closed TCP connection in reader-writer context using Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

Suppose I have a reader and a writer. A TCP connection is established between them using `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`. Provided that the writer does no read operation on the socket, is there a way for the writer to detect that the connection is closed by reader? By closed, I take to mean that the reader-side socket has been closed. I noted that a write error may not necessarily imply that the reader-side socket has been closed.

Comment: If your writer does not read, it should not care about closed connection :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887537/how-to-detect-when-a-boost-tcp-socket-disconnects