# Boost.Asio error code for "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: c++, boost-asio

In my tests my client gets occasionally, when trying to read from a boost socket, the error

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I have several questions:

1) What is the Boost error code I have to check for which is associated with this message?

2) What is the analogue on Linux systems? Can I catch the same error code?

3) In the server's logs I do not see a successful connection. But the client returns successfully from its connection attempt. Also `boost::asio::write()` succeeds, but also here the server does not receive anything. But when trying to read from the socket (after the send), I get above error message.

What is going on?

Comment: You can write to your socket with the client, server seems left alone, did you tell your router to redirect traffic of port xxx to your server ?

Comment: It is a sporadic error which normally does not occur. Also, there are many tests running starting the server and doing some communication and sometimes some of them fail because of this error. It looks to me like the server could not be started for some reason - but then I wonder, why establishing the connection does not fail already, but only the read.

Comment: Wireshark might be usefull in your case. An error on read can happen for various reasons such as a RST packet which IMO is what happens in your case : "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Comment: Why don't you just trace the value of the `error_code`? If you want platform independence, translate to the corresponding `error_condition` and detect on that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1) The `boost` error code is `boost::asio::error::connection_reset`; see `boost/system/error_code.hpp`.

2) The analogue on linux systems is `ECONNRESET`; see `errno.h`.

3) `connection_reset` is one of number of ways that a TCP socket can disconnect, see: [How to detect when a boost TCP socket disconnects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887537/how-to-detect-when-a-boost-tcp-socket-disconnects/19891985#19891985).

To determine precisely what is going on, I agree with `@user` and recommend that you install and use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to observe the TCP messages between your client and server.

Comment: The problem with using wireshark is that the disconnect happens only very rarely and I would have to somehow filter out all the successful connections to analyze the error case.

Comment: Wireshark has filters that should enable you to find the error case to analyse.