# boost asio server to know when the client closed the socket

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a client server application which works fine.
The client sends some message to the server after which it closes the socket (calls shutdown and close on the socket())

The server side of the code which reads the data is shown below:

```
while (1)
{
    try
    {
        int headerBytesReceived = asio::read( *sock.get(), boost::asio::buffer(inbound_header_) );
        std::cout << "headerBytesReceived : " << headerBytesReceived << "\n" << std::flush;
        //.......
        //.......
    }
    catch (system::system_error &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Server Error occured! Error code = "
            << e.code() << ". Message: "
            << e.what() << "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

The server reads the data in a thread in an infinite loop.
Now, when the client closes the socket, I want to get out of the loop graciously.
Right now, after the client is done sending the message and closing its socket, the catch is called with following error:

Server Error occured! Error code = asio.misc:2. Message: read: End of file

Is there a better way by which I can figure out inside the catch that the connection has been closed and I need to break the loop? By checking the error code ?
Ofcourse, I can remove the cout statement, but I want to know for logging purposes what the error was.

Answer (score 1):

If both ends perform a *successful* `shutdown`, the error will be `boost::asio::error::eof` to indicate that no more data is available.

Of course you could use the [`boost::asio::read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read.html) overload with the `boost::system::error_code` to prevent an exception. This might even be the better handling.

You could check for the error, and log instead that the connection was successfully shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a "better way" than reading the error code and determining whether it was a disconnect or a genuine error.

For more info see: [how to detect when a boost tcp socket disconnects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887537/how-to-detect-when-a-boost-tcp-socket-disconnects/19891985#19891985) and [what is the proper way to securely disconnect an asio ssl socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046034/what-is-the-proper-way-to-securely-disconnect-an-asio-ssl-socket)