# C++ Boost Asio - How to detect disconnection and make a list of all active connections

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am using Boost asio as a TCP server solution. I want my server and client to communicate over TCP binary protocol.

Here is my server code:

Server.cpp:

```
#include "Server.h"
#include "Session.h"

using namespace Vibranium;

void Server::do_accept()
{
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
   [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
   {
       if (!ec)
       {
           std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
           std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
       }

       do_accept();
   });
}
```

Here is Session.cpp:

```
#include "Session.h"

void Vibranium::Session::start() {
    do_read();
}

void Vibranium::Session::do_read() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout.write(data_, length);
            std::cout << "\n";
            do_write(length);
        }
    });
}

void Vibranium::Session::do_write(std::size_t length) {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
     [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
     {
         if (!ec)
         {
             do_read();
         }
     });
}
```

And here is `Session.h`:

```
#ifndef VIBRANIUM_CORE_SESSION_H
#define VIBRANIUM_CORE_SESSION_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

namespace Vibranium{
    class Session: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
    {
    public:
        Session(tcp::socket socket)
        : socket_(std::move(socket))
        {
        }
        void start();

    private:
        void do_read();
        void do_write(std::size_t length);
        tcp::socket socket_;
        enum { max_length = 1024 };
        char data_[max_length];
    };
}
#endif //VIBRANIUM_CORE_SESSION_H
```

Here is how I start the server:

```
#include "Config.h"
#include "Database/MySQLConnection.h"
#include "Implementation/LoginDatabase.h"
#include "Banner.h"
#include "Server/Server.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;
using namespace Vibranium;

int main() {
    //Don't mind Logger::FatalError it's just for coloring!
    Banner::Show(Logger::Error,"AuthServer");
    Config config("AuthServer");
    std::string defaultPort = "8080";
    MySQLConnectionInfo mySqlConnectionInfo(config, "LoginDatabaseInfo");
    LoginDatabaseConnection loginDatabaseConnection(mySqlConnectionInfo);
    loginDatabaseConnection.LoadDatabase();

    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        Server s(io_service, std::stoi(config.GetConfigValue("AuthServerPort", defaultPort)));
        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I catch new connections in `Server::do_accept()` and most likely there I'll have to fill a vector of all client end points. So in later stage I can create a function called for example `Send` to send to a specific client and another called `Broadcast` to send to all connected clients.

And here are the two questions:

1. What should be the type of the vector containing all connections? Where should I fill it?
2. How can I detect a disconnection so I can remove a client from that vector of connected clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.What should be the type of the vector containing all connections? Where should I fill it?

You could create a vector of sockets for storing clients:

```
vector<tcp::socket> clients; // adding by clients.push_back(move(socket)); after accept'ing
```

or create some wrapper class around socket and use it, for ex.

```
class Client
{ 
   tcp::socket socket;
public:
    Client (tcp::socket s) : socket{move(s)} {}
... some other logic
```

and use **`vector<Client>`** for storage.

> 2.How can I detect a disconnection so I can remove a client from that vector of connected clients?

You could use the first failure in reading/writing to socket as indicator for broken connection or use some sort of KEEP ALIVE message periodically, as ping message, to detect broken (or stale) connection.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give code example of how to detect disconnection ?

Comment: You can look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887537/how-to-detect-when-a-boost-tcp-socket-disconnects) as start point

Comment: Hey @StPiere i've added `Session.h` is that a wrapper class with close to your suggestion ?

Comment: yeah, basically it should fit. Vector of Session's should work.

Comment: On another note. Should the vector contain pointers of type Session or just session? I believe it should be vector of Session pointers, right ?

Comment: In your case it should be vector of shared pointers, as your Session is living through lambda invocation's as shared_ptr already. Also note: you dont need this in this capture:  [this, self]. [self] is sufficient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221559/discussion-between-venelin-vasilev-and-stpiere).

Comment: kak da ne znaem, we are neighbours :).

Comment: Bravo brato! Ot kude si?