# Boost.Asio: Async operations timeout

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, segmentation-fault, boost-asio

My Program acts as a server to which a client can connect. Once a client connected, he will get updates from the server every ~5 seconds. This is the `write`-function that is called every 5 seconds to send the new data to the client:

```
void NIUserSession::write(std::string &message_orig)
{
    std::cout << "Writing message" << std::endl;

    std::shared_ptr<std::string> message = std::make_shared<std::string>( message_orig );
    message->append("<EOF>");
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::async_write(this->socket_, boost::asio::buffer(*message),
        boost::asio::transfer_all(), boost::bind(&NIUserSession::writeHandler,
               this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred(),
               message 
               ));
}

void NIUserSession::writeHandler(const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t bytes_transferred, std::shared_ptr<std::string> message)
{
    std::cout << "Write Handler" << std::endl;
    if(error)
    {
        std::cout << "Write handler error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        this->disconnect();
    }
}

void NIUserSession::disconnect()
{
    std::cout << "Disconnecting client, cancling all write and read operations." << std::endl;
    this->socket_.lowest_layer().cancel();

    delete this;
}
```

If there is an error in the write operations the connection between the server and the client gets closed and all async operations are cancled (`this->socket_.lowest_layer().cancel();`).

The problem is that if the connection times out, `writeHandler` will not be called immediately. Instead, the write operations "stack up" until the first one reaches `writeHandler`.

This should be the normal output of the program:

```
Writing message
Write Handler
... Other stuff ...
... Other stuff ...
Writing message
Write Handler
```

If the connections times out, this is what happens:

```
Writing message
Write Handler
Write handler error: Connection timed out
Disconnecting client, cancling all write and read operations.
Write Handler
Write Handler
Write Handler
Write Handler
Write Handler
Write Handler
Write Handler
Write Handler
Write Handler
Write Handler
Write Handler
Segmentation fault
```

At the end, a segmentation fault rises. I think this is because `disconnect`is called while other async operations are still on their way.
I thought I could avoid it by using `this->socket_.lowest_layer().cancel();` directly after the first async operation fails, but it doesn't work.

How can I avoid a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you should not delete `this` when cancelling the operations since the callbacks for the pending I/O operations will still be invoked and then accessing `this` leads to undefined behavior. There are multiple ways to tackle this:

1. Don't write data until you actually know that previous data has been written. You could queue the `std::string` instances passed to `NIUserSession::write` in case an outstanding write is still pending and then actually write them in the handler when the outstanding write operation completes. That way you will not have multiple I/O operations in flight.
2. Inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and pass `shared_from_this()` instead of `this` to the `async_write` call (this is what the [Boost asynchronous TCP daytime server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) does). That way pending I/O operations will keep a reference to your class and the destructor will be called if all of them complete.

Comment: It doesn't lead to a segmentation fault. It leads to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Otherwise, +1

Comment: You need to VERY careful about object lifetimes when using asynchronous operations. The `boost::asio` [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html) use `shared_ptr` with good reason, see: [boot asio async function and shared ptrs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356742/boost-async-functions-and-shared-ptrs/19622084#19622084)

Comment: @sehe - thanks, edited:) My bad for using the incorrect wording.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it soon and respond :)