# Understanding Boost ASIO C++11 HTTP server example

Tags: boost-asio, shared-ptr

I'm reading the C++11 HTTP Server example at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/ and want to make sure I understand use of `shared_ptr` pervading this example. I couldn't see any direct explanation in the documentation.

I assume that the reason that connection inherits from  `std::enable_shared_from_this<connection>`, and is then passed in a `shared_ptr` (the captured `self`) to the handler registered with the the `async_read_some` in `connection::do_read()`, is to ensure that the `connection` object is kept alive for as long as the asynchronous read operation requires it. The `server` class creates a `shared_ptr` to a new connection in its `server::do_accept()` function accordingly.

I infer therefore that if the `shared_ptr` based design was not used (i.e., `connection` object just allocated on the stack in a `std::set<connection>` connections_ held by `connection_manager` instead of `std::set<connection_ptr>` and only `this` is captured by the handler passed to `socket_.async_read_some`), something unpleasant could happen due to an outstanding `async_read_some` handler's call occurring after the `connection` object no longer existed.

My question (assuming my previous understanding is correct) is, how necessary is all this use of `shared_ptr`/`shared_from_this()` and what circumstance(s) would lead to such an occurrence if no `shared_ptr`s were used, since a stack allocated `connection` would live for the duration of the connection_manager/server that owns it.

Comment: from generic view - if some object accessed from several threads - native solution use shared_ptr (reference counting) for manage it lifetime.

Comment: I recommend you look at the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356742/boost-async-functions-and-shared-ptrs) question.

Comment: Thanks, I think my main concern was that `shared_ptr` feels a bit intrusive, however if that is the idiomatic way to handle asynchronicity in ASIO and I haven't off the top of my head got a better alternative, then I accept that.

Comment: Not idiomatic at all. Your primary responsibility is to manage lifetime so that when the async handler gets called, all functions/methods get called on valid objects. It doesn't matter whether you allocate objects on stack or heap, just make sure they outlive any async callbacks. Shared pointers/`enable_shared_from_this` is just one way of managing object lifetime, although usually the preferred one.