# Why using shared_ptr in this boost SSL server example

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm checking this [SSL server example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp) and wondering why using `shared_ptr`. It start with the following method (`do_accept()`) and continuously using `auto self(shared_from_this())` in the `session` class to extend its lifespan between handlers.

**Q:** Is it possible to use a `tcp::socket` member inside `session` class and avoid `shared_ptr`? What modification must be applied?

```
void do_accept()
{
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), context_)->start();
            }

            do_accept();
        }
    );
}
```

Inside `session` class:

```
void do_handshake()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server, 
        [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                do_read();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Read cppreference on `std::shared_from_this()` it will cause runtime error if `this` isn't owned by a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: *"and continuously using ... to extend its lifespan"* - seems like you have already realized the purpose

Comment: You would have to write code to manage the session's lifetime to ensure the session doesn't cease to exist while a handler is pending. Every call to `shared_from_this` would be replaced with some kind of increment to a reference count for the session and every completion of dispatched operation would have to decrement it. And if you mess up making sure every increment results in precisely one decrement in every possible code path, your code will crash or leak memory. Yuck. Why are you looking to replace an elegant solution with a crufty one?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, really thanks for your comment, I am studying that example, and what I wants to know is the possible alternative solution to more realize the `shared_ptr` concept. What I thought is using an array of `session` in the `server` class and instead of creating `tcp::socket` in the lambda routine (argument section), create it in the `session` constructor.